# Matching an exact string in a SQL.Replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a for loop that searches through a SQL query and replaces 'CT.Item(i).ParameterName' with its actual value:

```
Dim SQLQP As String = SQL

For i=0 To CT.Count - 1
    SQL = SQL.Replace("CT.Item(i).ParameterName, "'" & CT.Item(i).Value & "'")

    SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace(CT.Item(i).ParameterName, "''' + " & CT.Item(i).ParameterName & " + '''")'.Replace("'%'", "''%''")
     End If
Next
```

'CT.Item(i).ParameterName' are parameter names (example: @p1, @p2, @p3 etc.)
The problem is that if there is a parameter name called @p10, the above loop sees it as "@p1" + "0", so when it goes to change @p1 it also changes @p10 and leaves a 0 hanging around. How can I avoid this issue?

The other solutions I have found when searching either don't account for punctuation or use REGEX, which is not applicable inside a SQL.replace function.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: I have solved the issue with 'SQL' by reversing the loop. However, now I am getting the same problem with 'SQLQP':

The else statement

```
Else
   SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace(CT.Item(i).ParameterName, "''' + " & CT.Item(i).ParameterName & " + '''")
```

returns:

```
[some sql code]... WHERE  ([RI].[INSTRUCTION_TIME]  >= ''' + @p1 + ''') AND ([RI].[ITEM_CATEGORY_UID]  IN (''' + @p2 + ''',''' + @p3 + ''',''' + @p4 + ''',''' + @p5 + ''',''' + @p6 + ''',''' + @p7 + ''')) AND ([RI].[ITEM_DETAIL_UID]  IN (''' + @p8 + ''',''' + @p9 + ''',''' + ''' + @p1 + '''0 + '''))')
```

''' + ''' + @p1 + '''0 + ''' is incorrect, it should be ''' + @p10 + ''', everything else is correct.

EDIT 2

As requested, here is SQLQP before the 'replace'

```
[some sql]...WHERE  ([RI].[INSTRUCTION_TIME]  >= @p1) AND ([RI].[ITEM_CATEGORY_UID]  IN (@p2,@p3,@p4)) AND ([RI].[ITEM_TYPE_UID]  IN (@p5)) AND ([RI].[ITEM_DETAIL_UID]  IN (@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10))
```

And here is what it should look like:

```
[some sql]...WHERE  ([RI].[INSTRUCTION_TIME]  >= ''' + @p1 + ''') AND ([RI].[ITEM_CATEGORY_UID]  IN (''' + @p2 + ''',''' + @p3 + ''',''' + @p4 + ''')) AND ([RI].[ITEM_TYPE_UID]  IN (''' + @p5 + ''')) AND ([RI].[ITEM_DETAIL_UID]  IN (''' + @p6 + ''',''' + @p7 + ''',''' + @p8 + ''',''' + @p9 + ''',''' + @p10 + '''))
```

Comment: It's early, I haven't had my coffee but could you try reversing the loop? `For i=CT.Count-1 to 0 Step -1`

Comment: That's a neat little hack, thanks for the suggestion. It did work specifically for the SQL variable. Unfortunately there is another part to that loop that I did not mention just to keep it simple (see updated loop). Although "SQL" now has the expected values, SQLQP now has the exact same problem as SQL did before the reversed loop

Comment: Can you show some example data and what the expected result is with this new issue? I'm not sure why you care about the % if you 're just doing the same thing. With the code you originally supplied, this would replace **@P1** or **%@P1%** with the appropriate parameter, `.Replace()` knows nothing nor cares about anything else other than the match. And as far as the apostrophe goes, if you're using the parameters correctly, there is no need to wrap types, the parameters handle this when you specify the type in the `.Add` method.

Comment: I have updated my question with some data and what is expected instead. Bearing in mind that this not my code. I am debugging someone else's piece of software so I am not sure why % is necessary. As for the apostrophes, if they are not used I get an error saying that I need to give a value to @p1

Comment: OK, it's time to show an exact example of a string before the replace and what it should look like after the replace occurs because I don't understand why you're not just replacing the parameter. Why are the `'''` or '%' even involved in the replace method. I understand they're needed for the IN clause values but it should still just be a matter of replacing a parameter. And for some reason it eludes me as to why you need 3 inside a string, it's not like you're trying to put literal quotes inside a string and have repeat.

Comment: I also think I understand what you're doing here but if I do, then my next statement is going to be that when you build those **IN** clauses, you need to include the apostrophe's there.

Comment: [updated the original post as requested] The ''' is needed because for some reason SQLQP expects the parameters as strings (unlike the 'SQL' variable). If they are not presented as strings and I leave SQLQP as it is, I get an error saying that @p1 needs to be given a value. As for the % I have no idea why they are there but I don't need to worry about them as where the error is, the loop skips them and jumps straight to the 'Else' statement.

Comment: If I add: 'SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace("''' + ''' + @p1 + '''0 + '''", "''' + @ p10 + '''")' to the Else statement, the problem is solved and there are no more errors. However, if ever there was to be a p11, p12 etc. the problem would return. It is not an efficient way of solving the problem.

Comment: ok, I've solved my problem thanks to your help. I will add the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved thanks to @Charles May:

```
SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace(",", " , ")
SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace(")", " )")
SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace("(", "( ")

For i = CT.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    SQL = SQL.Replace(CT.Item(i).ParameterName, "'" & CT.Item(i).Value & "'")
    SQLQP = SQLQP.Replace(" " + CT.Item(i).ParameterName + " ", "''' + " & 
CT.Item(i).ParameterName & " + '''")
     End If
  Next
```